# What is the expected payoff in an asymmetric first sealed bid price auction with uniform distributions?

Tags: probability, game-theory, auction-theory

A has an IID uniform distribution in [0,6] for item X.
B has an IID uniform distribution in [2,4] for item X.

There is an auction X, highest bidder wins and pays what they bid. The player's payoff is their value minus their bid, v-b. If they don't have the highest bid, they don't win the auction and get payoff of 0. The distributions are common knowledge but the realization is unknown. (for example B knows that A has a value between 0 and 6 but does not know that it is a 4.)

What is the expected payoff of A and B when they play their optimal strategies?

Comment: What do you consider an "optimal strategy"?

Comment: Are there many different kinds? Bayesian Nash Equilibrium would be good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-price_sealed-bid_auction

@jorki